# Site icons mucked up again

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looks like the sprite offsets are out of sync again:

[image]

Comment: Same here after cache refresh indeed...

Comment: I think what they're trying to say here is that mSE is getting QA'd (the icon for mSO is QA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A beta site is about to launch, so in preparation we modified the favicon sprite sheet that is used in a bunch of places.

Looks like the corresponding CSS update didn't go through.

This is in the process of being fixed and will be out in the next build (rev 2014.2.20.1382, Meta rev 2014.2.20.1967).

Comment: [Will it also fix this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iCT6W.png)? Thanks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - oh wow. Is that still happening for you? The fix has already been pushed, so if a hard refresh isn't helping, that's a brand new spanking and unrelated bug.

Comment: Was persistent but seem to have resolved it by shutting down and re-launching.

Comment: Huh. OK - was wondering if it might have been just one specific server, but might have been the browser.

Comment: I see proper icons again :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - how about dead people?

Comment: Them too; granny says "Hi!"